# Missing VM in old portal - To Reset SSH password for Linux Ubuntu in Azure

Tags: ubuntu, azure, password

I built a Ubuntu server in Azure, stopped and started the server and the IP changed which may have caused the password to reset?!

I cannot seem to login via SSH anymore as password seems to not work. So I'm now trying to reset the password.

Reset password option in the new portal says 'coming soon' the virtual machine is not shown in the old portal at all.

I've managed to connect using Azure CLI to see if it would give me further options.

However the Virtual Machine is showing within the new portal (under Virtual Machines).

This virtual machine is missing completely from the old management portal (under classic and standard virtual machines)

When I run the following commands, it shows my production storage... which contains my production VM

```
PS C:\> azure vm disk list
 info:    Executing command vm disk list
 + Fetching disk images
 data:    Name                                                 OS
 data:    ---------------------------------------------------  -----
 data:    Production-1-bj134d83-Production-1-os-144120938061  Linux

PS C:\> azure vm extension set Production-1 VMAccessForLinux Microsoft.OSTCExtensions 1.* --private-config-path \intel\PrivateConf.json
info:    Executing command vm extension set
 + Getting virtual machines
 error:   No VM with name "Production-1" found
 info:    Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\username\.azure\azure.err
 error:   vm extension set command failed
```

However It will not show me my production VM name whereby I'm trying to reset the password using the following command

```
PS C:\> azure vm extension set Production-1 VMAccessForLinux Microsoft.OSTCExtensions 1.* --private-config-path \intel\PrivateConf.json
 info:    Executing command vm extension set
 + Getting virtual machines
 error:   No VM with name "Production-1" found
 info:    Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\username\.azure\azure.err
```

error:   vm extension set command failed

I don't quite understand why the VM shows in the new portal but not the old.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you created a VM in ARM mode (Azure Resource Manager) that is the new mode available only in the new portal (https://portal.azure.com).

If you have created a VM in ARM Mode, this one will not show in old [classic] Azure Management Portal (http://manage.windowsazure.com/).

In new portal, if VM appears in Virtual Machine section then it is a VM in ARM Mode. If it appears in Virtual Machine Classic section, then it is a VM is ASM (old mode available in old portal).

To reset local password on a Linux VM, you need the VMAccess Extension for Linux and the latest version in your case because you have an ARM mode VM (a december update to this agent make it compatible with ARM : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/using-vmaccess-extension-to-reset-login-credentials-for-linux-vm/)

hope this help

Stanislas